# Cancelling like terms from either sides while proving equality in mathematical induction problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, induction

I was doing a mathematical induction problem.
**Problem**:
For all natural numbers n, prove that:
$1 × 2 × 3~+~2 × 3 × 4~+~.~.~.~+~n(n+1)(n+2)~=~\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}$
**Solution**:

1. For all natural number n, let P(n) denote the given statement.
   Then we can write:
   $P(n):~1 × 2 × 3~+~2 × 3 × 4~+~.~.~.~+~n(n+1)(n+2)~=~\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}$
2. **Basic step** (n = 1)

$\begin{array}{ll}
\phantom{\Rightarrow~}P(1): & 1(1+1)(1+2) \\
{} & =~\frac{1(1+1)(1+2)(1+3)}{4} \\
{\Rightarrow~} P(1): & 1 × 2 × 3 \\
{} & =~\frac{1 × 2 × 3 × 4}{4} \\
{\Rightarrow~} P(1): & 6 \\
{} & {}=~6 \\
\end{array}$
**So P(n) is true for n = 1**

3. **Inductive step:** (n = k) and (n = k+1)
   (i) n = k
   $P(k):~1 × 2 × 3~+~2 × 3 × 4~+~.~.~.~+~k(k+1)(k+2)~=~\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{4}$
   Assume that, the above result is true.
   (ii) n = k+1
   $\begin{array}{ll}
   \phantom{\Rightarrow~}P(k+1): & 1 × 2 × 3~+~2 × 3 × 4~+~.~.~.~+k(k+1)(k+2)~+~[(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)] \\
   {} & =~\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)}{4} \\
   {\Rightarrow~} P(k+1): & \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{4}~+~[(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)]~\color {green}{\text{[Using result in (i)]}} \\
   {} & =~\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)}{4} \\
   {\Rightarrow~} P(k+1): & \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)~+~4[(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)]}{4} \\
   {} & =~\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)}{4} \\
   {\Rightarrow~} P(k+1): & \frac{k~+~4[1]}{4}~\color {red}{\text{[Cancelling like terms on either sides]}} \\
   {} & =~\frac{(k+4)}{4} \\
   {\Rightarrow~} P(k+1): & \frac{k+4}{4} \\
   {} & =~\frac{k+4}{4} \\
   \end{array}$
   **So P(k+1) is true**
4. Thus P(k+1) is true whenever P(k) is true. Hence by the principle of mathematical induction, P(n) is true for all natural number n.

In the above calculation, I have cancelled (k+1), (k+2) and (k+3) from either sides. This is mentioned by the text written in red colour. Is this type of cancelling of like terms permitted? Do I need to work each side independently? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: In my view, this cancellation is bad style. Better: Start with the left-hand side of $P(k+1)$, and use algebra and $P(k)$ to build a chain of equalities to the right-hand side of $P(k+1)$. <> The same criticism holds for any "two-column proof" that starts with an statement $P$ to be shown and ends with a tautology $Q$. Strictly, the work shows "$P$ implies $Q$." If each step of the proof is logically reversible, the argument can be run backward, proving "$Q$ implies $P$," but few people check those details, which can lead to wrong proofs and apparent paradoxes.

Comment: Definitely problematic style-wise. Just *prima facie*, the sum is never $(k+4)/4$, which leaves the ending hanging there.

Comment: More specifically, the **final line** of the mathematical portion of the proof should look like this: $$(1)(2)(3) +  (2)(3)(4) + \cdots + k(k+1)(k+2) + (k+1)(k+2)(k+3) = \textstyle{\frac14} (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$$

or this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i(i+1)(i+2) =  \textstyle{\frac14} (k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)$$

Comment: Let me double down on this point: Starting with what you intend to prove, and deriving a true result from that does *not* prove anything. For example: A "proof" that $1 = 2$: $$1=2$$ Multiply both sides by the same constant: $$0\cdot 1 = 0 \cdot 2\\0 = 0$$ TRUE! The steps I took are mathematically valid. But what I did was derive $0 = 0$ from $1 = 2$, when it needs to derive $1 = 2$ from $0 = 0$. And while the steps I took were valid, they are not reversible.

Comment: In your case, the steps you took are reversible. But the point of a proof is to demonstrate to your audience that the statement is true. When you leave reversing the argument so that it runs in the correct direction to your audience, you have failed to complete the proof. And as a question of style, prepending every line with $\implies P(k+1):$ is just adding noise that offers no clarity at all.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree with your view point. Thank you for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable suggestions. I am now in a better position to deal with mathematical induction problems.